# como validar datos en un editext usando web service

Tags: android

Al ingresar dato en un editext, debo verificar si ese dato ya existe. Tengo el siguiente segmento de codigo, pero me da error y no se por que. Agradezco sus comentarios

```
telef.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, HttpUrl,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String ServerResponse) {

                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        try{
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(ServerResponse);


                            String returnState= jsonObject.getString("returnState");
                            String returnData= jsonObject.getString("returnData");
                            int r1,r2;
                            r1= Integer.parseInt(returnState);
                            r2=Integer.parseInt(returnData);

                            if ((r1==1) && (r2==2)){
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The phone number is registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                telef.requestFocus();
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                     }
                }
                ,
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {


                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Need internet access", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("mobile_no", telef.getText().toString());

                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
});
```

Comment: nos podrias decir un poquito mas cual es el requerimiento y cuales son los valores que necesitas comparar para validar ese edittext

Comment: esa parte del programa es para ingresar un nuevo usuario. lla idea es que al usuario ingresar el numero de telefono (que es el campo clave), el programa de una vez revise si ya esta registrado ese numero